# wordpress login - insert email from GET?

Tags: wordpress, get

i have a pretty difficult question here:

Is it possible to PRE - insert the email address in the corresponding email input from a GET request into the default wordpress form?

Comment: Can you give us more details or code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a detailed reference how to customize the WordPress login form https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form

Basically you can customize almost every aspect of the login form in terms of HTML.

If you want a quick solution without modifying code, you can register an additional *Javascript* that can read the URL query parameters from `window.location.href` and append it as email/username field placeholder/value attribute.

Here is a topic how to read URL GET parameters with Javascript [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)